# Getting Corrupt Base64 Encoded Image

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I have tried google and stackoverflow but not able to get a satisfactory answer I am a newbie and trying to encode image send/upload to server then decode same image in base64 image and show in my collectionview's Cell's imageview.

1. I have encoded the image in base64 successfully, I have checked the encoded string in online base64 formatter and getting my image in output so my encoding is working fine.

2  Getting the below error while decoding.....

```
<Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Unsupported marker type 0x6c 
<Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0x6c
```

I am using the below code to decode the image

```
NSString *imageURL  =  [imagename objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSData *imageData   =  [Base64 decode:imageURL];

ImageView.image     =  [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Any Suggestion and Advice will be appreciated....

Comment: The URL is base-64 encoded?  Are you sure?

Comment: Yes looks like you need to pull that from the url, and then decode that data from base64... if you know that data is base64 encoded.

Comment: @trojanfoe- NO I dont have a URL, I have  only encoded string like this (eD6VIWApmQ/PGO1RPMACD0qN5woxVV5Sx+XmgCUy/NwacJjgcXZnFuCDipo0KEdx3qe4gGW4wc01OQRjpxTSsrir1Odq) of image to upload on server and trying to download that encoded string in image format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
NSString *imageString  =  [imagename objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@",imageString]];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

ImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Is `@"data:image/png;base64,%@"` a URL?

Comment: ITs a URI Scheme http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme - works a treat for me when I've got a base64 encoded string

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  Cheers.

Comment: @Flexicoder-  Thanks for reply but still getting the same Error